# I want to prevent users from interacting with my page when 'Content-Lock' is on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm building a custom theme in wordpress (Please no plugin suggestions, i'm at max capacity there) and have it set up where all the content is locked until someone enters their first name/ or email.

Now, the page loads the content lock (which blurs sidebar and main content area on the right) immediately upon load. 
However, everything is blurred but buttons and essentially everything under the locking div is usable.

This obviously needs to be prevented.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

 
 var imagecontent = $('.image-content');
    var textcontent= $('.text-content');
    var header = $('h2');

    imagecontent.addClass('content-blurred');
    textcontent.addClass('content-blurred');
    header.addClass('content-blurred');
    body.addClass('content-locked');

    // to show the 'enter-details' modal //

    var unlockModal = $("#unlock-modal");
    var lockblock= $(".lockblock");
    var lockblock2= $(".lockblock2");
    var pagelock=$(".pagelock");
    var enterdetails= $('#enter-details');

    pagelock.click(function(){
        unlockModal.modal('show');
  });
    
    function setupUnlockForm() {
    var unlockForm = $('.unlock-form');
    var rules = {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        };
        var subscriptionForm = wp.template.subscriptionForm;
        if (subscriptionForm && subscriptionForm.firstNameKey) {
            rules['firstName'] = {
                required: true
            };
        } else {
            unlockForm.find('[name=firstName]').hide();
        }
        if (subscriptionForm && subscriptionForm.lastNameKey) {
            rules['lastName'] = {
                required: true
            };
        } else {
            unlockForm.find('[name=lastName]').hide();
        }

        unlockForm.on('submit', function (event) {
            var form = $(this);
            form.addClass('disabled');
            event.preventDefault();
        }).each(function () {
            var form = $(this);
            form.validate({
                rules: rules,
                submitHandler: function () {
                    var email = form.find('[name=email]').val();
                    var firstName = form.find('[name=firstName]').val();
                    var lastName = form.find('[name=lastName]').val();
                    unlockModal.modal('hide');
                    body.removeClass('content-locked');
                    return false;
                },
                invalidHandler: function () {
                    form.removeClass('disabled');
                }
            });
        });
    }
    });
```

There are HTML elements that need to be completely unusuable until the use enters their information. For example, the '.btn' below, when clicked, will load content that users that havent entered info should NOT see.

Whats best practice here?

```html
<span class="btn">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>
</span>
```

---

Comment: What happens if I disable JS in my browser? Do I get full access?

Comment: I believe no because for dynamic content, I have manual 'content-blurred' classes added on them that are removed in js when the function is triggered.

Comment: Just double checked and yeah, it will show you the content if you disable javascript. However, i'm not too concerned about that since the majority of my users wont do that and secondly....if they do see the content its not a huge deal. It's just for conversion.

Comment: Your safest bet is to load in the new content with ajax after they have entered the information or take them to another page. I am in total agreement with @rnevius because if JavaScript is disabled in the browser or the user can manipulate Javascript, people can exploit your page.

Comment: Hey there. Like I said, its not a big  concern for me if someone disabled JS in their browser....because thats going to be not even 1% of our users.